# Is there a way to distinguish between different `Rc`s of the same value?

Tags: rust, identity, smart-pointers, reference-counting

Here's an example:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MyId;

pub fn main() {
    let rc_a_0 = Rc::new(MyId);
    let rc_a_1 = rc_a_0.clone();
    let rc_b_0 = Rc::new(MyId);
    let rc_b_1 = rc_b_0.clone();

    println!("rc_a_0 == rc_a_1: {:?}", rc_a_0 == rc_a_1);
    println!("rc_a_0 == rc_b_0: {:?}", rc_a_0 == rc_b_0);
}
```

Both `println!`s above print `true`. Is there a way distinguish between the `rc_a_*` and `rc_b_*` pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can cast `&*rc` to `*const T` to get a pointer to the underlying data and compare the value of those pointers:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MyId;

pub fn main() {
    let rc_a_0 = Rc::new(MyId);
    let rc_a_1 = rc_a_0.clone();
    let rc_b_0 = Rc::new(MyId);
    let rc_b_1 = rc_b_0.clone();

    println!(
        "rc_a_0 == rc_a_1: {:?}",
        &*rc_a_0 as *const MyId == &*rc_a_1 as *const MyId
    );
    println!(
        "rc_a_0 == rc_b_0: {:?}",
        &*rc_a_0 as *const MyId == &*rc_b_0 as *const MyId
    );
}
```

prints

```
rc_a_0 == rc_a_1: true
rc_a_0 == rc_b_0: false
```

Answer (score 30):

*[2017](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/04/27/Rust-1.17.html) stabilization update (in 2020).*

In Rust 1.17 and forward, you can use [`Rc::ptr_eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.ptr_eq). It does the same as [`ptr::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.eq.html), without the need of converting the `Rc` to a reference or pointer.

#### Reference Equality

As the other answers mention `Rc::ptr_eq` (and `ptr::eq`) checks for reference equality, i.e. whether the two references "point" to the same address.

```rust
let five = Rc::new(5);
let same_five = Rc::clone(&five);
let other_five = Rc::new(5);

// five and same_five reference the same value in memory
assert!(Rc::ptr_eq(&five, &same_five));

// five and other_five does not reference the same value in memory
assert!(!Rc::ptr_eq(&five, &other_five));
```

*The example is from the Rust `Rc::ptr_eq` docs.*

#### Value Equality

`Rc` implements `PartialEq`, so simply use `==` as always, to perform value equality, i.e. whether the values are equal, irrelevant of whether they reference the same address in memory.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

let five = Rc::new(5);
let other_five = Rc::new(5);

let ten = Rc::new(10);

assert!(five == other_five);

assert!(ten != five);
assert!(ten != other_five);
```

Answer (score 7):

The same answer as Dogbert, but *maybe* a bit cleaner:

```
use std::ptr;

println!(
    "rc_a_0 == rc_a_1: {:?}",
    ptr::eq(rc_a_0.as_ref(), rc_a_1.as_ref())
);
println!(
    "rc_a_0 == rc_b_0: {:?}",
    ptr::eq(rc_a_0.as_ref(), rc_b_0.as_ref())
);
```

```
rc_a_0 == rc_a_1: true
rc_a_0 == rc_b_0: false
```

In short, you want *reference equality*, not *value equality*. A raw pointer's value is the memory address, so comparing the value of a raw pointer is equivalent to reference equality.

See also:

- [How to check if two variables point to the same object in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39463760/155423)
- [Why can comparing two seemingly equal pointers with == return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47489449/155423)

Comment: For comparing pointers, it is probably good practice to always cast to `*const MyType` first, or at least specify the type in `ptr::eq::<MyType>(...)`. Otherwise, you might be comparing the wrong type (e.g. `&&MyType` instead of `&MyType`, or `Deref`ed values).