# How to check if two variables point to the same object in memory?

Tags: pointers, memory, rust

For example:

```
struct Foo<'a> { bar: &'a str }

fn main() {
    let foo_instance = Foo { bar: "bar" };
    let some_vector: Vec<&Foo> = vec![&foo_instance];

    assert!(*some_vector[0] == foo_instance);
}
```

1. I want to check if `foo_instance` references the same instance as `*some_vector[0]`, but I can't do this ...
2. I don't want to know if the two instances are equal; I want to check if the variables point to the same instance in the memory

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "reference equality".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is the function [`ptr::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html):

```
use std::ptr;

struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let foo_instance = Foo { bar: "bar" };
    let some_vector: Vec<&Foo> = vec![&foo_instance];

    assert!(ptr::eq(some_vector[0], &foo_instance));
}
```

Before this was stabilized in Rust 1.17.0, you could perform a cast to `*const T`:

```
assert!(some_vector[0] as *const Foo == &foo_instance as *const Foo);
```

It will check if the references point to the same place in the memory.