# Why can comparing two seemingly equal pointers with == return false?

Tags: rust

I want to test if two objects of type `Rc<Trait>` contain the same instance of a concrete type, so I compare pointers to the objects inside `Rc` for equality. It seems to work correctly if all the code resides in the same crate but fails when multiple crates are involved.

In Rust 1.17 the function [`Rc::ptr_eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.ptr_eq) was added, which as of Rust 1.31, exhibits the same cross-crate issue as the manual pointer comparison used in this question.

This is the implementation of crate `mcve` (`src/lib.rs`):

```
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait ObjectInterface {}

pub type Object = Rc<ObjectInterface>;

pub type IntObject = Rc<i32>;

impl ObjectInterface for i32 {}

/// Test if two Objects refer to the same instance
pub fn is_same(left: &Object, right: &Object) -> bool {
    let a = left.as_ref() as *const _;
    let b = right.as_ref() as *const _;
    let r = a == b;
    println!("comparing: {:p} == {:p} -> {}", a, b, r);
    r
}

pub struct Engine {
    pub intval: IntObject,
}

impl Engine {
    pub fn new() -> Engine {
        Engine {
            intval: Rc::new(42),
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Object {
        return self.intval.clone();
    }
}
```

I test the implementation with the following code (`tests/testcases.rs`):

```
extern crate mcve;

use mcve::{is_same, Engine, Object};

#[test]
fn compare() {
    let mut engine = Engine::new();

    let a: Object = engine.intval.clone();
    let b = a.clone();
    assert!(is_same(&a, &b));

    let r = engine.run();
    assert!(is_same(&r, &a));
}
```

Running the test results in the following output:

```
comparing: 0x7fcc5720d070 == 0x7fcc5720d070 -> true
comparing: 0x7fcc5720d070 == 0x7fcc5720d070 -> false
thread 'compare' panicked at 'assertion failed: is_same(&r, &a)'
```

How is it possible that the comparison operator `==` returns `false` although the pointers seem to be the same?

A few observations:

- The comparison returns `true` when both objects (`a` and `b`) live in the same crate. However, the comparison returns `false` when one of the objects (`r`) was returned by the function `Engine::run`, which is defined in another crate.
- The test correctly passes when I put the test function inside `lib.rs`.
- The problem can be fixed by defining `struct Engine { intval: Object }`, but I'm still interested in the *why*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When is a "pointer" not a "pointer"? When it's a *fat pointer*. `ObjectInterface` is a trait, which means that `&dyn ObjectInterface` is a *trait object*. Trait objects are composed of **two** machine pointers: one for the concrete data and one for the *vtable*, a set of the specific implementations of the trait for the concrete value. This double pointer is called a fat pointer.

Using a nightly compiler and [`std::raw::TraitObject`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html), you can see the differences:

```
#![feature(raw)]

use std::{mem, raw};

pub fn is_same(left: &Object, right: &Object) -> bool {
    let a = left.as_ref() as *const _;
    let b = right.as_ref() as *const _;
    let r = a == b;
    println!("comparing: {:p} == {:p} -> {}", a, b, r);

    let raw_object_a: raw::TraitObject = unsafe { mem::transmute(left.as_ref()) };
    let raw_object_b: raw::TraitObject = unsafe { mem::transmute(right.as_ref()) };
    println!(
        "really comparing: ({:p}, {:p}) == ({:p}, {:p})",
        raw_object_a.data, raw_object_a.vtable,
        raw_object_b.data, raw_object_b.vtable,
    );

    r
}
```

```
comparing: 0x101c0e010 == 0x101c0e010 -> true
really comparing: (0x101c0e010, 0x1016753e8) == (0x101c0e010, 0x1016753e8)
comparing: 0x101c0e010 == 0x101c0e010 -> false
really comparing: (0x101c0e010, 0x101676758) == (0x101c0e010, 0x1016753e8)
```

It turns out that (at least in Rust 1.22.1) each *code generation unit* creates a separate vtable! This explains why it works when it's all in the same module. There's [active discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46139) on if this is a bug or not.

When you annotate the `new` and `run` functions with `#[inline]` the consumers will use that vtable.

---

As [Francis Gagné said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489449/why-can-comparing-two-seemingly-equal-pointers-with-return-false/47490007?noredirect=1#comment81937050_47490007):

> You can change `as *const _` to `as *const _ as *const ()` to turn the fat pointer into a regular pointer if you only care about the value's address.

This can be cleanly expressed using [`std::ptr::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html):

```
use std::ptr;

pub fn is_same(left: &Object, right: &Object) -> bool {
    let r = ptr::eq(left.as_ref(), right.as_ref());
    println!("comparing: {:p} == {:p} -> {}", left, right, r);
    r
}
```

Comment: Whow. That's insightful, thank you! Although knowing about fat pointers I didn't think they were at the root of the issue. I have played with them and it seems `IntObject`s have different vtables depending on the create in which they are created. This is... unexpected... looks like object identity is not as straight-forward as hoped.

Comment: @kazemakase You can change `as *const _` to `as *const _ as *const ()` to turn the fat pointer into a regular pointer if you only care about the value's address.

Comment: @FrancisGagné Excellent! That should work for my use case.